# Combine union and sum with diffrent column of view

Tags: mysql, union, sql-view

[image: My]

I have View here

What I want to try is to make the `v_total_project` looks like that.
I have try this code

```
select o.id_project AS id_project,
sum((o.office_expense + m.misc_expense)) AS total_expense 
from v_office_project o inner join v_misc_project m on o.id_project = m.id_project
group by o.id_project, m.id_project
```

I know my code will not print the `v_misc_project.id_project`. So I tried the Union to print both id_project, and got error different numbers of column.

```
select o.id_project AS id_project
from v_office_project o
union
select m.id_project as id_project,
sum((o.office_expense + m.misc_expense)) AS total_expense 
from v_office_project o inner join v_misc_project m on o.id_project = m.id_project
group by id_project
```

So, is there another way to do that?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Fancy formatting is best left to your application code.  SQL is clumsy for such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    o.id_project AS id_project,
    sum(
        o.office_expense + ifnull(m.misc_expense, 0)
    ) AS total_expense
FROM
    v_office_project o
LEFT JOIN v_misc_project m ON o.id_project = m.id_project
GROUP BY
    id_project
UNION
    SELECT
        m.id_project AS id_project,
        sum(
            ifnull(o.office_expense, 0) + m.misc_expense
        ) AS total_expense
    FROM
        v_office_project o
    RIGHT JOIN v_misc_project m ON o.id_project = m.id_project
    GROUP BY
        id_project
```

In the first select of your union you are missing the field for your expenses.

Also the join was missing, added it. Instead of `INNER JOIN` use a `LEFT` or `RIGHT Join`, otherwise you only get results for `id_project`'s which are in both tables.

Added `ifnull()` in the calculation, because the `LEFT` / `RIGHT` joins can return `null`, which has to be treated as 0.